# hamper someone to V?

Tags: collocations, to-infinitive

Can "hamper" be used in the format "hamper somebody to [verb]," as in the following?

> The stock market crash hampered the company to expand into the German market.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. **hamper** doesn't take an infinitival complement like that.

> The crash hampered the company's expansion into the German market.

Many speakers would also say

> The crash hampered the company from expanding into the German market.

but that strikes my ear as marginal,  as it treats **hamper** as an analog of **prevent**.